# LSCOLORS actual color values

Tags: rgb, gnome-terminal

I find that the default colors I get with apps like gnome-terminal are often nearly unreadable. In particular, the bright green for executables is unreadle with a white background.

I can use LSCOLORS to remap executable to be red instead of bright green (or whatever), but what I'd rather do is to make the bright green a shade that's not quite so close to white.

Is there a file somewhere that maps the color numbers in LSCOLORS to RGB values?

Comment: The exact RGB values of the colours depend on the terminal application that you're using. Consult its documentation for how to change bright green to a more minty shade, if that's what you want.